We searching way to copy pages from azure devops wiki to confluence with automations
we open to suggestions for tools or scripts or ideas :).
We searching way to copy pages from azure devops wiki to confluence with automations
we open to suggestions for tools or scripts or ideas :).
We searching way to copy pages from azure devops wiki to confluence with automations :)

There are two types DevOps wiki, assume you are using default team project wiki which contains Markdown(.md) files.

Confluence uses a different format (Atlassian Wiki markup or XHTML storage format) for its pages.
As per the doc markdown-confluence/publish GitHub Action, you can publish markdown file to Confluence via github actions task:

In github action, you can firstly clone the devops wiki and then publish to Confluence.

Downvoting because: 1) such badly asked questions should not be answered (you should vote to close instead), 2) this answer contains code as image.
